# AngularJs - How do i Keep $Http data between templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made an **$http** request for API which returns simple json object.

now i need to store this data in some way so the $http call will be preformed only once along all template url's and will be paste to *'MainController'*.
what is the best solution for it?

```
angular.module('myApp' ,['ngRoute'])

.factory('MasterData' , function($http ){
    var responseData;
    $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA')
    .then(function(response){
         responseData = response.data;
          return responseData;
    })

})

.controller('MainController' , function($scope , MasterData ){

})
```

Comment: [Caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching)?

Comment: Caching is the only solution for it?
Can't i use constant for storing objects in Angular?

Comment: You can. But the cache already do that for you, why would you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what my options are :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a service and cache the result of the $http-request. Services are singletons and thus the call will only be made once.

```
.service('MasterService', function ($http, $q) {
  var data;
  function getData() {
    var deferred = $q.defer()
    if (data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    } else {
      $http.get('someUrl')
        .then(function(response){
          data = response.data;
          deferred.resolve(data);
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    getData : getData
  };
})
```